# Passing an array/list of strings in a query parameter razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I need to save filter values when sorting, the problem comes when ex: user selects 2 months or more than 1 status in a filter, then the filters dont save. Right now I have sorting working in an anchor tag, with form I can make it work but I would prefer anchor tag.

this is the url I need to get:
http://localhost:57255/applications?EmployeeName=&SelectedYear=&SelectedStatuses=Aktiivne&SelectedStatuses=Lõppenud

this is the url I get:
http://localhost:57255/applications?sortField=AccountingStatus&isDescending=False&SelectedStatuses=System.String%5B%5D

I Understand why I get that url, but I have no clue how to make it work.

Action:

```
<a asp-action="Index"
                       asp-route-sortField="VacationStatus"
                       asp-route-isDescending="@(Model.SortField == "VacationStatus" ? !Model.IsDescending : false)"
                       asp-route-EmployeeName="@Model.EmployeeName"
                       asp-route-SelectedYear="@Model.SelectedYear"
                       asp-route-SelectedMonths="@Model.SelectedMonths"
                       asp-route-SelectedStatuses="Model.SelectedStatuses"
                       asp-route-SelectedAccountingStatus="@Model.SelectedAccountingStatus">
                        Staatus <i class="fa-solid fa-sort ms-2"></i>
                    </a>
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ApplicationsFilters filters)
    {
        var viewModel = await _applicationsProvider.Provide(filters);
        
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Viewmodel:

```
public record ApplicationsViewModel : ViewModel<ApplicationsViewModel>, IViewModel
{
    public record VacationApplicationView
    {
        public required int Id { get; init; }
        public required string FullName { get; init; }
        public required string PermitType { get; init; }
        public required string Duration { get; init; }
        public required int VacationLength { get; init; }
        public required string VacationStatus { get; init; }
        public bool IsSentToAccounting { get; init; }
    };

    public required IEnumerable<VacationApplicationView> Vacations { get; init; }
    public string? Comment { get; init; }

    public string? EmployeeName { get; init; } = "";
    public string? SelectedYear { get; init; }
    public List<string> SelectedMonths { get; init; }
    public string[] SelectedStatuses { get; init; } = Array.Empty<string>();
    public string? SelectedAccountingStatus { get; init; } = "";
    public string? SortField { get; init; } = "";
    public bool IsDescending { get; init; }

    public List<SelectListItem> YearSelectList = Enumerable.Range(2020, DateTime.Today.Year + 5)
        .Select(year => new SelectListItem(year.ToString(), year.ToString())).ToList();

    public List<SelectListItem> MonthSelectList = new()
    {
        new("Jaanuar", "1"),
        new("Veebruar", "2"),
        new("Märts", "3"),
        new("Aprill", "4"),
        new("Mai", "5"),
        new("Juuni", "6"),
        new("Juuli", "7"),
        new("August", "8"),
        new("September", "9"),
        new("Oktoober", "10"),
        new("November", "11"),
        new("Detsember", "12")
    };

    public List<SelectListItem> StatusSelectList { get; init; }

    public List<SelectListItem> AccountingStatusSelectList = new()
    {
        new("Saatmata", "Saatmata"),
        new("Saadetud", "Saadetud")
    };

    public interface IProvider
    {
        public Task<ApplicationsViewModel> Provide(ApplicationsFilters filters);
    }

    public record Provider : IProvider
    {
        private readonly IQueryDispatcher _queryDispatcher;

        public Provider(IQueryDispatcher queryDispatcher)
        {
            _queryDispatcher = queryDispatcher;
        }

        public async Task<ApplicationsViewModel> Provide(ApplicationsFilters filters)
        {
            var query = new GetVacationsQuery(filters.ToSpec());
            var vacations = await _queryDispatcher
                .Dispatch<GetVacationsQuery, IReadOnlyList<VacationApplication>>(query);

            return new ApplicationsViewModel()
            {
                SortField = filters.SortField,
                IsDescending = filters.IsDescending,
                EmployeeName = filters.EmployeeName,
                SelectedYear = filters.SelectedYear,
                SelectedMonths = filters.SelectedMonths,
                SelectedStatuses = filters.SelectedStatuses,
                SelectedAccountingStatus = filters.SelectedAccountingStatus,

                Vacations = SortVacations(vacations, filters.SortField, filters.IsDescending),
                
                StatusSelectList = ApplicationsFilters.GetStatusStrings()
                    .Select(status => new SelectListItem { Value = status, Text = status })
                    .ToList()
            };
        }

        private IReadOnlyList<VacationApplicationView> SortVacations(
            IReadOnlyList<VacationApplication> vacations, string sortField, bool isDescending)
        {
            IEnumerable<VacationApplication> SortedVacations = vacations;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField))
            {
                if (sortField == "Name")
                {
                    SortedVacations = isDescending
                        ? SortedVacations
                            .OrderByDescending(v => v.Permit.Employee.Name.FirstName, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("et-EE"), true))
                            .ThenByDescending(v => v.Permit.Employee.Name.LastName, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("et-EE"), true))
                        : SortedVacations
                            .OrderBy(v => v.Permit.Employee.Name.FirstName, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("et-EE"), true))
                            .ThenBy(v => v.Permit.Employee.Name.LastName, StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("et-EE"), true));
                }
                
                else if (sortField == "VacationType")
                {
                    SortedVacations = isDescending
                        ? SortedVacations.OrderByDescending(v => v.Permit.Type)
                        : SortedVacations.OrderBy(v => v.Permit.Type);
                }
                
                else if (sortField == "VacationPeriod")
                {
                    SortedVacations = isDescending
                        ? SortedVacations.OrderByDescending(v => v.Duration.Start)
                            .ThenByDescending(v => v.Duration.End)
                        : SortedVacations.OrderBy(v => v.Duration.Start)
                            .ThenBy(v => v.Duration.End);
                    
                }
                
                else if (sortField == "VacationStatus")
                {
                    var date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
                    IEnumerable<VacationApplication> pendingVacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationStatus == null);
                    IEnumerable<VacationApplication> activeVacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationStatus?.Accepted == true && v.Duration.Start <= date && v.Duration.End >= date);;
                    IEnumerable<VacationApplication> endedVacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationStatus?.Accepted == true && v.Duration.End < date);;
                    IEnumerable<VacationApplication> acceptedVacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationStatus?.Accepted == true && v.Duration.Start > date);;
                    IEnumerable<VacationApplication> deniedVacations = vacations.Where(v => v.VacationStatus?.Accepted == false);;

                    SortedVacations = pendingVacations;
                    SortedVacations = SortedVacations.Concat(endedVacations);
                    SortedVacations = SortedVacations.Concat(activeVacations);
                    SortedVacations = SortedVacations.Concat(acceptedVacations);
                    SortedVacations = SortedVacations.Concat(deniedVacations);

                    SortedVacations = !isDescending
                        ? SortedVacations
                        : SortedVacations.Reverse();
                }
                
                else if (sortField == "AccountingStatus")
                {
                    SortedVacations = isDescending
                        ? SortedVacations.OrderByDescending(v => v.IsSentToAccounting)
                        : SortedVacations.OrderBy(v => v.IsSentToAccounting);
                }
            }

            return SortedVacations.Select(vacation => new VacationApplicationView
            {
                Id = vacation.Id,
                FullName = vacation.Permit.Employee.Name.FullName,
                PermitType = vacation.Permit.Type.DisplayName,
                Duration = vacation.Duration.ToString(),
                VacationLength = vacation.Duration.GetDurationInDays(),
                VacationStatus = vacation.GetVacationStatusString(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)),
                IsSentToAccounting = vacation.IsSentToAccounting
            }).ToList(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Filters:

```
public class ApplicationsFilters
{
    public static readonly string Active = "Aktiivne";
    public static readonly string Ended = "Lõppenud";
    public static readonly string Pending = "Ootel";
    public static readonly string Accepted = "Kinnitatud";
    public static readonly string Denied = "Tagasi lükatud";
    
    public static readonly string Saatmata = "Saatmata";
    public static readonly string Saadetud = "Saadetud";

    public string? EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string? SelectedYear { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedMonths { get; set; } = new();
    public string[] SelectedStatuses { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
    public string? SelectedAccountingStatus { get; set; }

    public string SortField { get; set; } = "";
    public bool IsDescending { get; set; }
    
    public Spec<VacationApplication> ToSpec()
    {
        Spec<VacationApplication> statusSpec = Spec<VacationApplication>.Any;
        Spec<VacationApplication> spec = Spec<VacationApplication>.Any;

        if (!EmployeeName.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            if (SortField == "")
            {
                SortField = "Name";
                IsDescending = false;
            }
            spec &= new EmployeeVacationsSpec(EmployeeName!);
        }
        
        if (!SelectedYear.IsNullOrEmpty() && int.TryParse(SelectedYear, out int year))
        {
            if (SelectedMonths.Any() && int.TryParse(SelectedMonths[0], out int firstMonth))
            {
                if (SelectedMonths.Count == 2 && int.TryParse(SelectedMonths[1], out int secondMonth))
                {
                    spec &= new MonthlyVacationsSpec(year, firstMonth, secondMonth);
                }
                else
                {
                    spec &= new MonthlyVacationsSpec(year, firstMonth, firstMonth);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                spec &= new YearlyVacationsSpec(year);
            }
        }
        
        if (SelectedStatuses.Any() && !SelectedStatuses[0].IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            statusSpec = Spec<VacationApplication>.None;
            if (SelectedStatuses.Contains(Active))
            {
                statusSpec = statusSpec || new ActiveVacationsSpec();
            }

            if (SelectedStatuses.Contains(Ended))
            {
                statusSpec = statusSpec || new EndedVacationsSpec();
            }

            if (SelectedStatuses.Contains(Pending))
            {
                statusSpec = statusSpec || new PendingVacationsSpec();
            }

            if (SelectedStatuses.Contains(Accepted))
            {
                statusSpec = statusSpec || new AcceptedVacationsSpec() &&
                              !new ActiveVacationsSpec() &&
                              !new EndedVacationsSpec();
            }

            if (SelectedStatuses.Contains(Denied))
            {
                statusSpec = statusSpec || new DeniedVacationsSpec();
            }
        }

        if (SelectedAccountingStatus?.Contains(Saatmata) is true)
        {
            spec &= !new SentToAccountingVacationsSpec();
        }

        if (SelectedAccountingStatus?.Contains(Saadetud) is true)
        {
            spec &= new SentToAccountingVacationsSpec();
        }
        
        var fullspec = new AndSpec<VacationApplication>(spec && statusSpec);

        return fullspec;
    }
    
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetStatusStrings()
    {
        yield return Active;
        yield return Ended;
        yield return Pending;
        yield return Accepted;
        yield return Denied;
    }
    
    
}
```

First I tried to make it work with list and then with an array, both ways unsuccessfully. I understand you cannot use C# in an anchor tag. Any chance this could work or do I need to give up and just return a single string with separator or smth.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, is it possible to combine all the query string into one string?

Comment: @TinyWang I am trying to make it work right now with returning a string and parsing it later into an array, but the problem now is that I cannot set the filter values as my url looks like ....SelectedStatuses=Aktiivne,Ootel instead of SelectedStatuses=Aktiivne&SelectedStatuses=Ootel. I can get the correct filtered values sorted but the user wont see the selected statuses

Comment: could you pls add the rest of your codes to make it complete for a minimal sample so that we could try to reproduce the issue and troubleshoot it?